# Copy from another workbooks the last row with value to the active workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I got 35 files and a master one. In the files , Sheet1, column D has the values 480 and 0. How can i copy the last row ( from all the 35 files ) that has 480 in column D in the master file Sheet3 ? Until now i have used the code for copy the last row but i can't make it to search the column D for value then copy. I really want to run the macro from the master not from the many files (now actually a made a macro to open all the files and run macro cop to copy the last rows but now i must copy only the last row that has 480 value in column D ).Thank you.

```
Sub cop()
```

`Dim lastS1Row As Long      
    Dim nextS2Row As Long    
    Dim lastCol As Long       
    Dim s1Sheet As Worksheet, s2Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim source As String      
    Dim target As String      
    Dim path As String
    Dim DestLast As Long

    source = "Sheet1"    
    path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\2.xlsx"  
    target = "Sheet3" 
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled    
    Set s1Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(source)           
    Set s2Sheet = Workbooks.Open(path).Sheets(target)  
    lastS1Row = s1Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    nextS2Row = s2Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lastCol = s1Sheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  
    For lCol = 1 To lastCol
        s2Sheet.Cells(nextS2Row, lCol) = s1Sheet.Cells(lastS1Row, lCol)
    Next lCol

    s2Sheet.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    s1Sheet.Activate

End Sub`

Comment: `480 value in column D` what do you mean?

Comment: Hi, number 480 ( 8 hours in minutes ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I'm assuming the 480 is a number and not a string.  I added an If-Then to check if last row, column D is equal to 480.

```
Sub cop()

    Dim lastS1Row As Long
    Dim nextS2Row As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim s1Sheet As Worksheet, s2Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim source As String
    Dim target As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim DestLast As Long

    source = "Sheet1"
    path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\2.xlsx"
    target = "Sheet3"
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    Set s1Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(source)
    Set s2Sheet = Workbooks.Open(path).Sheets(target)
    lastS1Row = s1Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    nextS2Row = s2Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    lastCol = s1Sheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If (s1Sheet.Cells(lastS1Row, 4).Value = 480) Then ' This is where you check the last row, column D.
        For lCol = 1 To lastCol
            s2Sheet.Cells(nextS2Row, lCol) = s1Sheet.Cells(lastS1Row, lCol)
        Next lCol
    End If

    s2Sheet.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    s1Sheet.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you answer.It works great (i really didn't find/think that " if " clause ) . How can i make this macro run from the master file? Now the macro must be run from the 35 files and i really want to run it from the master file - one click for all. Thank you.

Comment: Using the Dir command inside a loop is what I would do.  If the 35 files are all together in the same folder that would make it easier. The Dir command will return a string of the file name and it can be used to build the path for `Set s2Sheet = Workbooks.Open(path).Sheets(target)`